# Need help on mail composer in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, email

I have warning on with error message below. Please help.

`Assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDeelegate>' from incompatible type 'MyViewController'`
and
`Class 'MyViewController' does not implement the 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' protocol`

The code is

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 

{

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

//below bold code is warning 

    **picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;**

[picker setSubject:@"My first apps!"];


// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]; 


[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[picker setMessageBody:TextView.text isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as the error says: your class `MyViewController` doesn't conform to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol. Your interface line should look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

And, of course, you should be sure to implement `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` in your class.